# angularjs not working on weebly

Tags: angularjs, weebly

So my client has a website he's created on weebly and he wants me to add a page with some complex functionality. I went ahead and coded the page with angularJs, but now when I add it to weebly with an `embed code` element, the angular doesn't work. Any clue how to either

A) just add a page normally (.html file)

B) get angular to work within the weebly page

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out this issue, the angular was working with embed, but not on weebley's editor site. Once deployed, the code worked fine

Answer (score 0):

I guess it would really depend on what you are trying to do. Please provide your code, for reference.

To directly answer your questions;

1. You can add, at least some, angular JS. (I haven't tested it all, but what I did worked)
2. With Weebly you do not have the ability to add **.html** files *as standard pages*.

   - You CAN add a 'Page Type' to the Theme. (which is essentially an HTML file).
   - You can add a page and then assign said page type.

~

Example, adding the following to the embed code element will work.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="">

<p>Input something in the input box:</p>
<p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
<p ng-bind="name"></p>
```